# Writing a variadic macro that uses the names of the arguments passed

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I want to write a variadic macro that somehow knows the names of the arguments passed.
For example:

The code:

```
int x = 2;
float f = 4.6;
char c = 'A';
char* str = "Bla bla";
PRINT("%d  %f %c  %s", x, f, c, str);     // calling the macro
```

shall produce the output

```
x=2 f=4.6 c=A str=Bla bla.
```

Hope someone knows the answer to that.

Comment: for the char print iss %c and not %s I updated the question with that

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be done.

Comment: To the OP: are you sure you want *exactly* that? It cannot be easily done! (But if you spend several days or weeks of work, you might get something close).

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's impossible in the exact way of your example: a string literal like `"%d  %f %c  %s"` can't be picked apart, augmented in the middle or modified by the C preprocessor. It can only work for single parameters because string concatenation allows to prepend another string to a string literal.

Comment: @Jens: Indeed. Of course automatically assembling a format string (say by passing a format together with the arguments or inferring them through C11 type generics) would probably be easier to use anyway

Answer (score 5):

Close but not exactly (only works for **single expression**) what the asker required:

```
#define PRINT(fmt, var) printf(#var " = " fmt, (var))
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRINT(fmt, var) printf(#var " = " fmt, (var))

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 2, y = 3;
    float f = 4.6;
    char c = 'A';
    char *str = "Bla bla";
    PRINT("%d\n", x);
    PRINT("%f\n", f);
    PRINT("%c\n", c);
    PRINT("%s\n", str);
    PRINT("%d\n", x+y);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: @Dipto Yes, you are right, and that is why I said 'close but not exactly' :-)

Comment: Typo: not *signal* but *single* variable!

Comment: @leeduhem Feel free to rollback. Looks like my edit erased yours.

Comment: @remyabel 'single' is fine. But I think 'single expression' is more accurate, this macro also works for `x+y`.

Answer (score 1):

Read *carefully* the documentation of [cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). In particular, about [macro arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments), [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification), [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation), and [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros). It is well explained there.

You probably might not be able to achieve exactly what you want, because you need to split the format string.

Perhaps lower your goals (e.g. accept only *one* argument for `PRINT`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967703/841108) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967723/841108) answers) or consider using a more powerful preprocessor like [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP).

You could also perhaps customize GCC (by adding your builtins) with e.g. [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) but that is probably not worth the weeks of efforts (for a newbie) required to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve what you want.

But something like this might be yours:

```
#define PRINT(fmt, val) fprintf(stderr, "%s=" fmt, #val, val)

...

int x = 2;
float f = 4.6;
char c = 'A';
char* str = "Bla bla";
// calling the macro:
PRINT("%d  ", x);
PRINT("%f ", f);
PRINT("%c  ", c);
PRINT("%s\n", str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly what you may want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x, (x)
#define FPRINTF(file, fmt, ...) fprintf(file, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTF(fmt, ...) FPRINTF(stdout, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
  int i = 42;
  char ch = 'a';
  char str[4] = "alk";

  PRINTF("%s=%s, %s=%c, %s=%d\n", 
    STRINGIFY(str), 
    STRINGIFY(ch), 
    STRINGIFY(i)
  );

  /* of just use printf directly: */
  printf("%s=%s, %s=%c, %s=%d\n", 
    STRINGIFY(str), 
    STRINGIFY(ch), 
    STRINGIFY(i)
  );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/Puts on Indiana Jones` hat/

I may be a tad too late, but I`m here to say that this problem does have a proper(-ish) solution.

First, some prerequisite defines ([explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048843/iterating-over-arguments-in-a-c-variadic-macro-yet-another-solution)):

```
#define L(c, ...) \
L4(c,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,##__VA_ARGS__) L4(c,0,1,,,,,,,,,##__VA_ARGS__) \
L4(c,0,2,,,,,        ##__VA_ARGS__) L4(c,0,3,        ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define L4(c, f, n, ...) \
L3(c,f,n##0,,,,__VA_ARGS__) L3(c,0,n##1,,,__VA_ARGS__) \
L3(c,0,n##2,,  __VA_ARGS__) L3(c,0,n##3,  __VA_ARGS__)

#define L3(...) L2(__VA_ARGS__, \
1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, )

#define L2(c, f, \
n00,n01,n02,n03, n04,n05,n06,n07, n08,n09,n0A,n0B, n0C,n0D,n0E,n0F, \
a00,a01,a02,a03, a04,a05,a06,a07, a08,a09,a0A,a0B, a0C,a0D,a0E,a0F, \
s, ...) L##s(c, f, n00, a00)

#define L1(c, f, n, a) c##f(n, a)
#define L0(c, f, n, a)
```

Then the code, which is actually an extension of @alk`s answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING1(n, a) #a, (a)
#define STRING0(n, a) , STRING1(n, a)
#define PRINTF(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, L(STRING, __VA_ARGS__))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 42;
    char ch = 'a';
    char str[4] = "alk";
    /** every var must be preceded with '%s' for its name to be shown **/
    PRINTF("%s=%s, %s=%c, %s=%d\n", str, ch, i);
    return 0;
}
```

This version is only suited for [0..16] arguments, but it can be easily extended to any argument count, especially to powers of 2. However, the more arguments it supports, the less elegant it looks.

P.S.: @BasileStarynkevitch has already provided all the right links to clarify how this works.

Answer (score -1):

The next works for me in gcc 4.7 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT(...) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
int x = 2;
float f = 4.6;
char c = 'A';
char* str = "Bla bla";
PRINT("%d  %f %c  %s", x, f, c, str); // calling the macro
}
```

(please note that i have edited the macro invocation changing a %s for a %c)

Regards

Comment: It does not also display the *name* `x` (just its value) which is what the OP wants.